# What strategies assist in destroying a team's nexus?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been playing LoL for a little over a month, and I thought that the strategy of the game was to destroy the other team's nexus without losing yours. However, I've been watching league games, and they hide in bushes and take golems from across the river and the announcers are always talking about gold. Why? Am I wrong about LoL? Is there really more to it than just destroying the enemy nexus? Is League of Legends really an in-depth strategy game, or do they hide and take golems to just have more fun?

Comment: The game is vastly more complex than you may think it is. The golems provides buffs for your champion that can greatly influence the game, depending on who they're on and how they use them. Gold is a great indicator of how many items you'll be able to buy, and so usually, the team with more gold wins the game. When you hide in a bush, the other team can't see you, so it's usually a good way of ganking someone (that is, catching them off guard, and killing them).

Comment: That's like saying Chess is nothing more than taking the enemy King. Yeah, that, and how to get to that point

Comment: Hi @conjim, unfortunately I'm voting to close your question as Not A Real Question because of its very broad and also very subjective. This is a question better asked on a discussion forum, not our site, as we focus on Q&A that can be directly answered. What your question as stated asks is basically "What is the point?" which is something that will be very subjective to each player. We cannot provide a definitive answer to this.

Comment: @FAE is there a way I could alter the question to allow it to stay up? and I dont find the question to broad its basically whats the point.

Answer (score 2):

The game is very much about gold. Gold, experience, buffs (from minions) and team work.

There are lots of elements in LoL which make it a fantastic game: jungling, ganking, getting dragon and baron, backdooring, team comp.

Destroying the enemy nexus is the main objective and the only way to win, but an enormous amount of events and variable go into destroying the other teams nexus.

Answer (score 2):

Well, destroying the Nexus isn't really a strategy, it's a goal. You use your strategy to achieve that goal. Several strats that come to mind:

1) Buff control. Controlling the neutral buffs is essential to winning the game. Blue and red buff are great for AP and AD champs respectively.

2) Dragon/Baron control. Try to control Baron/Dragon. Baron gives you a massive buff, drag gives you a nice global gold bonus, which leads me into the next strategy:

3) Gold and last hitting. Making sure you get the last hit on minions in lane will get you that gold. More gold = more items. More items = more pwnage.

Those are the main strategies. Obviously, LoL is a very complicated game and there are several factors and subtle things that go on in every game, but those are three big ones.